# How did this number come about in a volume integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

[image]

I have no idea why the volume is 8 in the first octant, I'm fine with the rest. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: You’ve misread it: that first line says that the total volume is $8$ *times* the volume in the first octant (because the volume in each octant is the same). The triple integral in the next line then gives the volume in the first octant.

Comment: Thanks very much, makes perfect sense now

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Brian noted in a comment, the intended meaning is that the volume is $8$ *times* the volume in the first octant. Needless to say, that's a rather sloppy way to write this.